# Disqus comments on Jekyll show when hosted on localhost but not when hosted on GitHubPages

Tags: html, yaml, jekyll, github-pages, disqus

I've created a blog type page using Jekyll and hosting it using GitHub pages. I've recently tried to add disqus comments; when inside my directory and I run a Jekyll serve and I access my page via localhost:4000 the comments are there and are fully functional. My problem comes when I push my changes and try to access it via my browser (grilla99.github.io), the changes are then not displayed. Why would this be happening?

My post.html looks like this

```html
<article class="post" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">

  <header class="post-header">
    <h1 class="post-title" itemprop="name headline">{{ page.title | escape }}</h1>
    <p class="post-meta">
      <time datetime="{{ page.date | date_to_xmlschema }}" itemprop="datePublished">
        {% assign date_format = site.minima.date_format | default: "%b %-d, %Y" %}
        {{ page.date | date: date_format }}
      </time>
      {% if page.author %}
        • <span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span itemprop="name">{{ page.author }}</span></span>
      {% endif %}</p>
  </header>

  <div class="post-content" itemprop="articleBody">
    {{ content }}
  </div>

    {% include disqus_comments.html %}
</article>
```

And my disqus_comments.html file looks like this:

```html
{% if page.comments %}
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>

/
*  RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.
*  LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT: https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables*/

var disqus_config = function () {
// this.page.url = PAGE_URL;  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
this.page.identifier = grilla99-github-io; 
};

(function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
s.src = 'https://grilla99-github-io-1.disqus.com/embed.js';
s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
(d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
})();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
{% endif %}
```

On my posts page inside my YAML I have set

> comments: true

Why is it not displaying when online and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following code

```
this.page.identifier = grilla99-github-io;
```

with

```
this.page.identifier = '{{ page.url | absolute_url }}';
```

Comment: That's because your site is not using the `disqus_comments.html` you posted in your question.. instead the site is using `disqus_comments.html` from Minima theme

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using the default Jekyll theme for your site.
Simply adding the following to your config file should be enough..

```
  disqus:
    shortname: my_disqus_shortname
```

Comment: This was useful, in that it registered disqus as attempting to show a comment area. However it shows the following:

'We were unable to load Disqus. If you are a moderator please see our troubleshooting guide.'

Comment: I will take a look at the troubleshooting guide, is there something obvious in my code that could be causing this?

Comment: [unrelated-tip] delete `_site` and `.sass-cache` from your repo.. GitHub Pages will create it automatically.. Then add those two paths to a file named `.gitignore` and add that file to your repo